# Relatively prime product divisibility

Tags: number-theory

Let $ a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}$ are pairwise coprime integers. Let $c$ be an integer that is divisible by each $a_{i}$.

Prove that $c$ is divisible by the product $$a_{1}\cdot\cdot\cdot a_{n}$$

I tried induction, saying that since $a_{1}|c$, $a_{2}|c$, and $gcd(a_{1},a_{2})=1$, that $lcm(a_{1},a_{2}) = a_{1}*a{2}$, so this is clearly divisible by the product. I then tried the induction step, but I don't think it holds that any subset product of integers is necessarily coprime to another subset product of the same integers. If not, then I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Don't you mean that only the $a_i$ are pairwise coprime, not the $a_i$ and also $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest if you use the *Fundamental Theorem* of Number theory, and write each
$a_i$ as $a_i=\prod_j{p_{i,j}}^{\alpha_{i,j}} \ $  where $p_{i,j}$ is prime, $\alpha_{i,j}\in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha_{i,j}\ge 1$.
Since these are *pairwise coprime*, for distinct $i\ne i'$ we have $p_{i,j}\ne p_{i',j'}$ for any $j,j'$.

From this, it easily follows (eithor with or without induction) that
$lcm(a_1,a_2,..,a_n)=a_1a_2..a_n$.

Comment: So I just want to say that each of these $a_{i}$ is a product of unique primes by the FTOArithmetic...And that from this product, I can say that the whole product of each $a_{i}$ is a unique representation of primes. Then $lcm(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n})$ is clearly the product, c. Thus c is divisible by all $a_{i}$. End?